# Css Menu Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfZUp.png)

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDBGC.png)

The two pictures above demonstrate my problem in the first picture the menu is active and everything is great but when I hide the menu the overflow of the body is still there I was wondering if there's a solution.

and in the second picture, I have my problem visually.

HTML

```
     <body>
      <header>
        <nav>
          <h1 class="logo">Home Page</h1>
          <svg
            class="menu"
            width="43"
            height="23"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <line
              class="line1"
              y1="1.5"
              x2="43"
              y2="1.5"
              stroke="black"
              stroke-width="3"
            />
            <line
              class="line2"
              y1="11.5"
              x2="28"
              y2="11.5"
              stroke="black"
              stroke-width="3"
            />
            <line
              class="line3"
              y1="21.5"
              x2="16"
              y2="21.5"
              stroke="black"
              stroke-width="3"
            />
          </svg>

          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="studies.html">Studies</a></li>
            <li><a href="interests.html">Interests</a></li>
            <li><a href="AboutMe.html">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>      
     </body>
```

before clicking the menu

```
.menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

this is my CSS code for it after clicking the menu and I tried to add `.body overflow-x: hidden` but it gives me the same problem.

```
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 11vh;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
```

this is my javascript code for the menu animation

```
   
const navSlide =()=>{

    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    menu.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        navLinks.forEach((link,index)=>{
           if(link.style.animation){
                link.style.animation = '';
            }else{
               link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index/ 7 + 0.3}s`;
        }
    }); 

});
};
```

and these are some of the keyframes I used for the menu to add more smoothness to the menu

```
@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the menu is still clickable here, you might want to set the `pointer-events` to `none` or `auto` (hidden or shown respectively) so the pannel becomes interactive only when shown (at opacity 1). Some doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Not sure what second screenshot is actually showing...Overflow controls when scrollbars shown or hidden. Are you talking about that type of overflow here?

Comment: i tried this but it didn't change anything

Comment: @vanowm the second picture is the unactivated menu... so instead of hiding it just go to the right and push the page with it

Comment: @Spectric surely

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now. A simple left:0 could do the trick on the menu. The magic hidden overflow comes when the CSS messes with transforms. Very hard to show on pictures, a gif could have helped

Comment: @savageGoat I tried left:0; but it just messed it up

Comment: The HTML you provided does not reproduce the error in the question. Could you please include all the code necessary to do so?

Comment: left or right depending on your parent I mean. If your upper icon has a float: right, it becomes more tweaky to fix, but if the whole menu (not the nav links) has a `width: 100%`, left:0 fixes it. The last case would be if you use the `display: block` to fill what's left, in that case, moving your nav links holder a bit down cancels the overlap. Worth noticing that this error only occurs on some browsers, not all

Comment: I wrote a little workaround, might not answer the question but could fix the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/b3qsd9h5/